# How do I disable being able to set the git commit message from the command line?

Tags: git, bash, zsh

I find that being able to specify the commit message in one go, tricks me into writing short one line commit messages. I often end up along the lines of `git commit -m "fix things"`. But whenever I leave off the `-m` option, and my editor pops up, I'm more likely to write a good commit message.

In the past I've created habits by disabling features I didn't want to use anymore. As example: I disabled the arrow keys in vim, which finally made me use hjkl. This was so effective, I want to try to do the same for the git commit messages. I want git (or bash or zsh) to yell at me for trying to use `commit -m`.

I *could* write a wrapper around the git command entirely, but maybe you have other solutions and I might learn something cool! I'm open to all sorts of magic and trickery.

Comment: Can't test right away, but try creating a function `mgit() { git "$@" -m ""; }`, and using `mgit` instead of `git`.  If `git` considers only the subsequent repeated arguments, then this should work.

Comment: Or like this `function git() { args="$@"; if [ -z $(grep "commit" <<< "$args")  ]; then git "$@"; else git "$@" -m ""; fi }` but proper way is to use hook

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ @devnull adding `-m ""` doesn't affect the previous option. `git commit -m "fix" -m ""` still just creates the commit with the message "fix".

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `prepare-commit-msg` hook in your `.git/hooks` directory to check the length of the message and reject the commit if the message is too short:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remove whitespace, at least 50 characters should remain.
if (( $(sed 's/\s//g' "$1" | wc -c) < 50 )) ; then
    echo Message too short. >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: +1 I use this technique to ensure my commit messages are [well-formed](http://git-scm.com/book/ch5-2.html#Commit-Guidelines).